# TypeError: admin.fireStore is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I'm trying to make a simple function that adds user data to my firestore on the creation of an account. To my knowledge I have everything correct, but it's obviously not working. One thing that I'm not sure if is weird is I have 2 package.json files, but I'll provide both of them.

Here is my index.js

```
import admin from "firebase-admin";
import express from "express";
import { onRequest } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";

const router = express.Router();

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(router);

const addUserData = onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  const addData = await admin.fireStore().collection("users").doc(req.uid).set({
    firstName: req.firstName,
    lastname: req.lastName,
    dob: req.dob,
    email: req.email,
  });
  res.send(addData.responseCode);
});

router.put("/addUserData", addUserData);

const api = onRequest(app);

export { api as app };
```

My package.json (inside functions folder)

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.4.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.10.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And my package.json outside my functions folder:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.10.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.4.1",
    "googleapis": "^122.0.0"
  }
}
```

This is my first time trying to use firebase and set up a project on my own so I may be missing something obvious, but I couldn't find anything from all the posts I looked at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would help

change `admin.fireStore()` to `admin.firestore()`

```js
const addData = await admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(req.uid).set({
    firstName: req.firstName,
    lastname: req.lastName,
    dob: req.dob,
    email: req.email,
  });
```

You should check [firebase authentication triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events)

Comment:  wow I feel like an idiot. That was the problem lol. Thanks for your help!